# Can we filter https packets using jpcap?

Tags: java, http, traffic, jpcap

Can we filter https packets using jpcap?
And if yes then is something special done on these packets before they are actually given to a user
Or nothing special?

Is there special handling for https packets which is not for http packets or both are done the same way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't filter anything with JPcap in the sense you mean. You can capture packets (and use a filter to define what is captured), but you cannot affect how, or whether, they are delivered to the target application in any way.

Comment: but then how to get only http data? any idea?